# mobile virtual keyboard make html body height 100% wired

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, virtual-keyboard

I'm making mobile page and all the layout is designed with percentage.
all the components in layout depends on body width, height.

When virtual keyboard is not present, there is no any problem.
But when virtual keyboard shows up, here is the problem.
I think a picture is worth a thousand words.

[image: without virtual keyboard]
[image: with virtual keyboard]

This shouldn't happen!
Can anyone knows the way to ignore virtual keyboard area?
Or suggest alternative way?

This is the code for fitting height 100%.
The reason why I used this code instead of css or viewport device-height is
that css height:100% and viewport device-height is never working whatever I tried.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var bodyWidth = $('html').width();
    var bodyHeight = $('html').height();  
    $('body').css("height", bodyHeight);
}
```

Comment: `height: auto` not working? Also can you create a jsfiddle or post a link?

Comment: I already tried almost all the options to make height 100% but they don't work. Only javascript above works. Site link is m.ct30days.com/signup.php

Comment: I change all of my web site layout. I changed height not 100% but i set height to width * ratio. Because of this, my site now have vertical scroll but it seems much better than before without virtual keyboard problem. I think my previous design, both width and height depend on screen width and height so that there is no any scoll, is not proper because it will destroy original design ratio.